# nginx load-balancing and reverse-proxy multiports : 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, load-balancing

I used two Icecast servers which host many webradios streams.
Each stream use a port between 8000 and 9000.

I use nginx (1.16.1 on Debian 10) to :

- easily allow HTTPS for all streams
- automatically change server on failure (ex.: server down). (high-availability / load-balance)

In fact, this is what I wish :

When user listen a stream on https://hosting.mydomain.com:8xxx , 
I want to transparently (proxify) send the request on one of the two Icecast's server.

Example :

If HTTPS and Icecast_1 is alive then send the request to Icecast_1.

If HTTPS and Icecast_1 is down then send the request to Icecast_2.

To do it, I've set the following :

```
#Icecast's cluster :
upstream backend {
    ip_hash;
    keepalive 64;
    #Icecast 1 :
    server 10.1.0.101 ;
    #Icecast 2 :
    server 10.1.0.102 ;

}


#SSL for all
server {

        listen 8000-9000 ssl ;
        server_name hosting.mydomain.com;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-ssl-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-ssl-error.log;

        # ssl on;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1 ;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/hosting.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/hosting.mydomain.com/privkey.pem;

        location / {
               resolver 8.8.8.8;
               proxy_pass http://backend:$server_port;
        }

}
```

I've a problem when I try to do something like this : "http://backend:$server_port".

In the web browser I've the error : 502 Bad gateway

In the errors logs on the server :  *1 no resolver defined to resolve backend .

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the server port in the upstream configuration.  Check if you can use the $server_port in stead of 6789.

```
upstream backend {
 ip_hash;
 keepalive 64;
 #Icecast 1 :
 server 10.1.0.101:6789 ;
 #Icecast 2 :
 server 10.1.0.102:6789 ;
}

server {

    listen 8000-9000 ssl ;
    server_name nginx.mydomain.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-ssl-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-ssl-error.log;

    # ssl on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1 ;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/hosting.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/hosting.mydomain.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
           proxy_pass http://backend;
    }

}
```

If you want to use $server_port, you can't use upstream, so, no load balancing.

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.1.0.101:$server_port;
    }
```

Comment: I tried to replace 6789 by $server_port, and I also revomed $server_port of proxy_pass . And nginx won't start :  nginx: [emerg] invalid port in upstream "151.80.47.212:$server_port"

Comment: And if you put the correct port number (is it 9999 ?? ).  what happened to the 10.1.0.101 ?

Comment: When I specify a port in the upstream, nginx starts. But when I tried this : https://hosting.mydomain.com:8014 , the request was sent on the port 80 of the backend. Do you have any idea what happened?

Comment: The part of this configuration doesn't deal with hosting.mydomain.com, only  nginx.mydomain.com.

Comment: Port 80 is the default, of course.  This will be used if you have a server defined without port number.

Comment: Sorry, it's a mistake , I just corrected this point with the following value : server_name hosting.mydomain.com.

Comment: You did restart nginx?  Can you show your current config in the original question?

Comment: Can you show your current config in the original question? -> I've corrected the value in the original post and on my server. The good value for server_name is : server_name hosting.mydomain.com .

Comment: If you look carefully, you will notice the port numbers are missing in the upstream configuration.  That is why they go to port 80.

Comment: You did restart nginx? Can you show your current config in the original question?

Comment: Are you trying h t t p ://hosting.mydomain.com:8019 or h t t p s ://... ?  If you are using https, I currently see only two possibilities.  A, you are connecting to another system, not the one you are modifiying.  B. there are other servers defined in your configuration.   Check the access and error logs.

Comment: OK, I'm going to try it myself.

Comment: I'm trying with h t t p s , like this : h t t p s://hosting.mydomain.com:8014

Comment: I've rebooted the machine with nginx , and now it's fine, the port 8014 specified on hosting.mydomain.com:8014 is correctly send on backend:8014 ...

Comment: How did you restart nginx?   Perhaps you can accept my answer?

Comment: Sorry, when I say the machine with nginx, I would say the machine where nginx is installed ...

Comment: I restart nginx with  :  systemctl restart nginx .

Comment: Perhaps you can accept my answer? -> In part, because my original request is how I can automatically specify the good port in the proxy_pass directive ( h t t p://backend:$good_port ) ?

Comment: I see.  Shall I set answer "you can't" ?

Comment: The response to my initial topic, is partial, because, my initial topic is something like how to dynamically set the good port to redirect the request (proxy_pass) to the good port on the backend server.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, it's very useful.

Comment: But , there are 50 webradios hosted on the servers (backend). Each uses a port between 8000 and 9000.

With the answer, that to propose to me this would amount to creating in NGINX as many configuration lines as there are webradios and servers used.

Or, in this case: 2 backend servers with 50 radios, which makes 100 configuration lines. ... It will be a nightmare to manage :'(

Comment: Why two servers?  High availability?  In that case, hide both behind a single IP address, and join them with keepalived.  So nginx thinks there is only one radio server.

Comment: Yes, two servers as indicated in the original section, it is to be able to change the server in the event of a breakdown (e.g. Server down). (high availability / load balance)

Comment: Read about keepalived.

Comment: I used nginx to avoid setting up a HA-Proxy or other heavier solution

Comment: But in my case it seem the KeepAlived or Haproxy is more indicated now.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and your time. You helped me a lot

Comment: HaProxy isn't heavy at all, on the contrary.  I used to have keepalived managing the haproxies, and the haproxies managed the available servers.

Answer (score 0):

@Gerard H. Pill , this is my current server's configuration :

```
#Icecast's cluster :
upstream backend {
    ip_hash;
    keepalive 64;
    #Icecast 1 :
    server 10.1.0.101:8014 ;
    #Icecast 2 :
    server 10.1.0.102:8014 ;

}


#SSL for all
server {

        listen 8000-9000 ssl ;
        server_name hosting.mydomain.com;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-ssl-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-ssl-error.log;

        # ssl on;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1 ;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/hosting.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/hosting.mydomain.com/privkey.pem;

        location / {
               resolver 8.8.8.8;
               proxy_pass http://backend;
        }

}
```

I saved it and I restarted nginx.

Answer (score 0):

@Gerard H. Pille , Thank you for your answers and your time. You helped me a lot

Comment: His own! LOL Help yourself, so ...